# Oil temp goes up when turkey breast is added - why?

Tags: deep-frying, turkey

Why does my oil temperature go up, from 350°F to 400° or 425°, when I add a bone-in turkey breast? It will remain there for about 20  minutes **without** the burner on.

I have done this twice now with same results. The turkey cooks fine but this puzzles me - any thoughts?

Comment: Richard is right, it's most likely a measurement problem. How are you measuring it? Is it possible that the oil is sitting still, but when the turkey piece is dropped, oil from hotter layers swirls close to the probe? Or that it's an infrared thermometer whose readout changes depending on the surface which reflects the rays?

Answer (score 2):

Where does the temperature readout come from?

I would be very curious indeed about the results of measuring the temperature with a thermometer directly in the oil.

As far as I know there is no exothermal chemical reaction between meat and oil, so adding a colder piece of meat to hot oil should ALWAYS reduce the temperature of the total volume (assuming that no extra heat is added from an external source)